# If $x + y \sim x$ in a commutative monoid, does this imply $y \sim 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid, congruence-relations

Let $(M,0,+)$ be a commutative monoid. A congruence relation is an equivalence relation, such that
$$
 a \sim b, c \sim d \quad \mbox{implies} \quad a + c \sim b + d. 
$$
for all $a,b,c,d \in M$.

> Fix some $x,y \in M$. Does $x + y \sim x$ imply $y \sim 0$? Do you know a counter-example?

Comment: Take $(\Bbb N,0,+)$ and $a\sim b$ if both $a,b$ are positive.

Comment: You really need to include some quantifiers for all of these things.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I did.

Comment: Since you just want this for some $x$, it can even be done with the congruence being $=$.

Comment: In $\mathbb N$ we have $x + y = x$ implies $y = 0$, or not? As the function $n \mapsto n + k$ has no fixed point for $k > 0$...

Comment: Yes, it can not be done in $\mathbb{N}$ with $=$, but it can be done in other monoids (ones that are not cancellative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimal counterexample**: $(M, \oplus)$ with $M = \{0, 1, 2 \}$, $x \oplus y = \min \{ x+y , 2\}$ and $1 \sim 2$. Then $1 \sim (1 \oplus 1)$ but $1 \not\sim 0$.